# Как закрыть окно tkinter при клике не на него

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, окно

Как закрыть окно tkinter (Python) при клике не на него

Comment: А кликнуть куда вы хотели бы?

Answer (score 1):

Вот так это можно сделать:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.bind("<Button-1>", lambda x: root.destroy())
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: В таком случае окно закрывается когда на него нажимают, а мне нужно наоборот, если нажали не на окно, а в другом месте, то окно закрывается